# Octobercms onstart flash message

Tags: octobercms

I'm using the User plugin and I wanted to know how can I flash messages to the user when they login (new session) and logout.

Tried using this when a client logs in, but it doesn't make sense as it will always show up when the page is refreshed.

```
<p data-control="flash-message" data-interval="5" class="success">
    {{message}}
</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you've set the 'message' variable? The October CMS documentation should help you with this https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-flash

Comment: Hi, just added the Flash::success(Successfully Logged in) on the method(onSignin->Account.php), then used the tag-flash to output the message. it works just not sure if it is good practice to edit the user plugin script.                                                                          /*
             * Redirect to the intended page after successful sign in
             */
            $redirectUrl = $this->pageUrl($this->property('redirect'))
                ?: $this->property('redirect');

            Flash::success('Successfully Logged in');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hooks/events

`rainlab.user.login`: The user has successfully signed in.

`rainlab.user.logout`: The user has successfully signed out.

> 1. Create a new Plugin with the builder
> 2. in the plugin.php write in the boot function:

```
    Event::listen('rainlab.user.login', function($user) {
     Flash::success(Successfully Logged in)
    });
    Event::listen('rainlab.user.logout', function($user) {
     Flash::success(Successfully Logged out)
    });
```

> 3. dont change the vendor code because is a bad practice.

more to the events 
https://octobercms.com/docs/services/events

and to the list of the user events
https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin#events